# How to download git repositories into Ubuntu WSL2 to run it in VS Code?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, github, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have installed Ubuntu WSL2 and have been working on some projects on Visual Studio Code for a while now. But I am unable to fetch the downloaded Git repositories from Windows.

I am expecting if there is a way to open downloaded Git repos in Ubuntu WSL2.

Answer (score 0):

So, when you want to open any git repo in WSL terminal you need perform following commands in WSL terminal:

```
    $ git clone repo-link
    $ cd repo-name
    $ code
```

After the following command, the cloned repo will open in both WSL terminal and  VS code as well.

Answer (score -1):

In windows open the control panel and from there click power options and from there you will see change advance settings and then there will be a line written "change setting that are currently unavailable ". Then untick the first option (it will include something about PC).
I hope it helps.